# Delete function deletes an item but it automatically comes back Error : React

Tags: reactjs

[Error Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/010Ps.gif)

I'm trying to delete an item from array of objects. But it deletes for a while but once I again click on it. It gets back. I just cant seem to update the array. Seems like it removes once but again gets the same data back. Example of error has been posted in the above gif.

**Menu.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Remove from './Remove';
const Menu = ({ items, removeFunc }) => {
  return (
    <div className='section-center'>
      {items.map((menuItem) => {
        const { id, title, img, desc, price } = menuItem

        return <Remove key={id} {...menuItem} removeFunc={removeFunc} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Menu;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import Menu from './Menu'
import Categories from './Categories'
import items from './data'
const allCategories = ['all', ...new Set(items.map((item) => item.category))]
var newTours;

function App() {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(items)
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(allCategories)
  

const removeFunc = (id) => {
  newTours = items.filter((tour) => tour.id !== id)
   setMenuItems(newTours)
}
  const filterItems = (category) => {
    if (category === 'all') {
      setMenuItems(items)
      return;
    }
    const newItems = items.filter((item) => item.category === category)
    setMenuItems(newItems)
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <section className='menu section'>
        <div className='title'>
          <h2>our menu</h2>
          <div className='underline'></div>
        </div>
        <Categories categories={categories} filterItems={filterItems} />
        <Menu items={menuItems} removeFunc={removeFunc} />
      </section>
    </main>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Remove.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Remove = ({ id, title, img, desc, price, removeFunc }) => {
  // const { id, title, img, desc, price } = items
  return (
    <article key={id} className='menu-item'>
      <img src={img} alt={title} className='photo' />
      <div className='item-info'>
        <header>
          <h4>{title}</h4>
          <h4 className='price'>{price}</h4>
        </header>
        <p className='item-text'>{desc}</p>
        <p className='item-text'>{id}</p>
        <button type='button' key={id} onClick={() => removeFunc(id)}>
          Delete {id}
        </button>
      </div>
    </article>
    // <div>

    //   {/* <button
    //    type='button'
    //    key={id}
    //    onClick={() => remove(id)}
    //  >
    //    Gone
    //  </button> */}
    // </div>
  )
}

export default Remove
```

**data.js**

```
const menu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'buttermilk pancakes',
    category: 'breakfast',
    price: 15.99,
    img: './images/item-1.jpeg',
    desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'diner double',
    category: 'lunch',
    price: 13.99,
    img: './images/item-2.jpeg',
    desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'godzilla milkshake',
    category: 'shakes',
    price: 6.99,
    img: './images/item-3.jpeg',
    desc: `ombucha chillwave fanny pack 3 wolf moon street art photo booth before they sold out organic viral.`,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'country delight',
    category: 'breakfast',
    price: 20.99,
    img: './images/item-4.jpeg',
    desc: `Shabby chic keffiyeh neutra snackwave pork belly shoreditch. Prism austin mlkshk truffaut, `,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'egg attack',
    category: 'lunch',
    price: 22.99,
    img: './images/item-5.jpeg',
    desc: `franzen vegan pabst bicycle rights kickstarter pinterest meditation farm-to-table 90's pop-up `,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: 'oreo dream',
    category: 'shakes',
    price: 18.99,
    img: './images/item-6.jpeg',
    desc: `Portland chicharrones ethical edison bulb, palo santo craft beer chia heirloom iPhone everyday`,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: 'bacon overflow',
    category: 'breakfast',
    price: 8.99,
    img: './images/item-7.jpeg',
    desc: `carry jianbing normcore freegan. Viral single-origin coffee live-edge, pork belly cloud bread iceland put a bird `,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: 'american classic',
    category: 'lunch',
    price: 12.99,
    img: './images/item-8.jpeg',
    desc: `on it tumblr kickstarter thundercats migas everyday carry squid palo santo leggings. Food truck truffaut  `,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    title: 'quarantine buddy',
    category: 'shakes',
    price: 16.99,
    img: './images/item-9.jpeg',
    desc: `skateboard fam synth authentic semiotics. Live-edge lyft af, edison bulb yuccie crucifix microdosing.`,
  },
  // {
  //   id: 10,
  //   title: 'quarantine buddy',
  //   category: 'shakess',
  //   price: 16.99,
  //   img: './images/item-9.jpeg',
  //   desc: `skateboard fam synth authentic semiotics. Live-edge lyft af, edison bulb yuccie crucifix microdosing.`,
  // },
]
export default menu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(items)
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(allCategories)
  

const removeFunc = (id) => {
  newTours = menuItems.filter((tour) => tour.id !== id)
   setMenuItems(newTours)
}
  const filterItems = (category) => {
    if (category === 'all') {
      setMenuItems(menuItems)
      return;
    }
    const newItems = menuItems.filter((item) => item.category === category)
    setMenuItems(newItems)
  }
```

***Check If it works.***

When you are clicking it changes the current state, and current state contains the desired items But when you are clicking again then you are fetching data again from your original data and the reason being you are getting the same data again.

Comment: Hi @AhmadNadeem, welcome to the community! Preferred way of saying Thank you here is to Accept or Upvote the answers. Accept the best one.

Comment: my reputation is less than 15. Will do when i will have more.

Comment: You can accept the answer by checking the Tick button if it answers your question.